# Increasing the clickable Textfield() size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to build a SwiftUI `Textfield` which should be clickable in the whole gray area to enter a text (to visualize it better I made a red frame).

The word "Search" as a placeholder shall be centered inside this box to make it look better.

I have the problem, that in the whole area beneath and above the word "Search" the box is not clickable.

[image: Textfield]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var searchText = ""

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        Spacer()

        TextField("Search", text: self.$searchText).foregroundColor(.primary)
            .frame(height: 40).border(Color.red) //This line is just to show what I want to achive to be clickable.
        Spacer()
    }
    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
    .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
    .cornerRadius(10.0)
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that. However i'll see if i can comeup with a workaround, if i do i'll be back to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, but you can implement something similar yourself.

You can create a custom text field and add a value to make it become first responder whenever the user click on the area surrounding your textfield.

So first of all what we are going to do is to create a `UIViewRepresentable` to make our custom `TextField`

```
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }

    }

    @Binding var text: String
    var isFirstResponder: Bool = false

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTextField.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) {
        uiView.text = text
        if isFirstResponder && !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder  {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
        }
    }
}
```

Now all we have to do is implement our `CustomTextField` as shown below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var clickableTextField = false
    var body: some View {
        
        
        HStack {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                Spacer()

            CustomTextField(text: $searchText, isFirstResponder: clickableTextField)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .frame(height: 40).border(Color.red)
                .border(Color.red)
            
                Spacer()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.clickableTextField = true
        }
        
    }
}
```

Voila! now your `TextField` is clickable as you requested.

[image: Result]